# remote API to create file under $JENKINS_HOME/jobs/jobName/

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

jenkins has an existing way to modify jobName/config.xml file through post data to url ../jobName/api/config.xml

is it possible to create other files under /JENKINS_HOME/job using the same way like config.xml?

if not, is there an existing plugin to implement my requirement?

if no existing plugin, I'm afraid I have to develop it by myself, so did jenkins provide the extention point which allow me do so?

Comment: What is your requirement? IIRC, user files can be kept under $JENKINS_HOME/userContent. I suppose you can upload files there and reference in the build

Comment: I'd like to create file under $JENKINS_HOME/jobs/jobName remotely. for example, when I post data to /jenkins/jobName/api/foo.xml. then I will see foo.xml created with the content I post.